# Add active class to li and parents through jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a beginner to javascript, I've been trying to add the `active` class to a `li` using jquery i.e. When its clicked, expand `li` and make it active:

```
  <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
           var url = window.location['pathname'];
           jQuery('li a').each(function() {
               if($(this).attr('href') == url)
                   $(this).parent().addClass('active');
           });
       });
  </script>
```

This only makes the sub-menu active but not expanded. But when I manually added the active class (as shown below) to treeview and li, it expanded and became active. How to dynamically add the `active` class through jquery?

```
<aside class="main-sidebar">
   <section class="sidebar">
      <ul class="sidebar-menu" data-widget="tree">
         <li class="header">MENU</li>
         <li class="treeview active">
            <a href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-table"></i> <span>USER</span>
            <span class="pull-right-container">
            <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
            </span>
            </a>
            <ul class="treeview-menu">
               <li><a href="{{ url_for('add')}}"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add</a></li>
               <li class="treeview active">
                  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Profile
                  <span class="pull-right-container">
                  <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
                  </span>
                  </a>
                  <ul class="treeview-menu">
                     <li class="active"><a href="{{ url_for('view')}}"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> View </a></li>
                     <li><a href="{{ url_for('settings')}}"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Settings </a></li>
                  </ul>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </section>
</aside>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

So, you need to apply `active` class on all `.treeview` using [parents](http://api.jquery.com/parents/):

```
$(this).parents('.treeview').addClass('active');
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, changing `parent()` to `parents()` fixed it:

`$(this).parents().addClass('active');`